# Some nethods in my main Activity are showing as never used

Tags: java, android, android-studio

These two methods `addUser()` and `viewDetails()` methods are not being used in this my main activity file. I could find the reason, I don't know where do I have to call them. I am using Android Studio.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText userName, password;

    DatabaseAdapter databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPass);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    }

    public void addUser(View view) {

        String user = userName.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();

        long id = databaseHelper.insertData(user, pass);
        if (id < 0) {
            Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
        } else {
            Message.message(this, "Successful");
        }
    }

    public void viewDetails(View view) {
        String data = databaseHelper.getAllData();
        Message.message(this, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not using them, why did you write them?

Comment: I am using them. but android studio shows, They are never used! i dont know how to resolve it

Comment: Where are you using them?

Comment: I have called other methods from other class in it. I using them to use those methods

Comment: You have to actually call the methods that you created when you want to use them. You've coded the functionality, now you have to actually call for that functionality somewhere else in the code otherwise the methods are unused.

Comment: That's not an errror, but a warning. You can ignore that. Or remove the unused methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching this code you are only declaring a function and give the definition of the function you are not using it or calling it .. any where that's why android studio show you not using this method's...
You can call this method like addUser(); or viewDetails();

Comment: Yes you can call these methods in oncreate after this line

Comment: databaseHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);